# A-Star Pathfinding | Hexagonal Grip

Tags: java, algorithm, path-finding, a-star, hexagonal-tiles

I'm a newbie and I'm facing such an awkward problem:

[image: img].

It seems like the algorithm has swallowed an extra hex. 
Could anybody point to my mistake?

So here is the code:

('ob' that appears in 1 and 2 is set of 'obstacles')

1.Pathfinding func:

```
private static Node pathFinding(Vector2i startHex, Vector2i goalHex, HashSet<Vector2i> ob, int movesLeft) {
    start = new Node(startHex);
    goal = new Node(goalHex);

    if (distance(start, goal) > movesLeft) return null;

    TreeSet<Node> openSet = new TreeSet<>(new NodeComparator());
    HashSet<Node> closedSet = new HashSet<>();

    start.cameFrom = null;
    start.g = 0;
    start.h = distance(start, goal);
    start.f = start.g + start.h;
    openSet.add(start);

    float tentativeScore;

    while (!openSet.isEmpty()) {
        current = openSet.pollFirst();
        if (current.coords.equals(goal.coords)) {
            return current;
        }
        closedSet.add(current);
        for (Node node : getNeighbors(current, ob)) {
            node.g = distance(start, node);
            tentativeScore = current.g + distance(current, node);

            if (!closedSet.contains(node) || tentativeScore < node.g) {
                node.g = tentativeScore;
                node.h = distance(node, goal);
                node.f = node.g + node.h;
                node.cameFrom = current;
                openSet.add(node);
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

2.Neighbors:

```
private static final Vector2i[] directions2i = {
        new Vector2i(0,-1), new Vector2i(1,-1), new Vector2i(1,0),
        new Vector2i(0,1), new Vector2i(-1,1), new Vector2i(-1,0)
};

private static List<Node> getNeighbors(Node origin, HashSet<Vector2i> ob) {
    List<Node> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        Vector2i dir = new Vector2i(origin.coords.x + directions2i[i].x, origin.coords.y + directions2i[i].y);
        if (!ob.contains(dir))
            list.add(new Node(dir));
    }
    return list;
}
```

3.Heuristic:

```
static float distance(Node a, Node b) {
    return (Math.abs(a.coords.x - b.coords.x) + Math.abs(a.coords.y - b.coords.y) + Math.abs(a.coords.x +a.coords.y -b.coords.x -b.coords.y)) / 2;
}
```

4.And just in case here is Node and Comparator classes:

```
public class Node {
public Node cameFrom;
public Vector2i coords;
float g, h, f;

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return coords.x * 100000 + coords.y;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Node oth = (Node) o;
    return this.coords.equals(oth.coords);
}

Node(Vector2i coords) {
    this.coords = new Vector2i(coords);
}
}

private static class NodeComparator implements Comparator<Node> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Node o1, Node o2) {
        return Float.compare(o1.f, o2.f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not an answer, but: The code is a bit hard to read and understand, and particularly, hard to "debug" just by looking at it. But just in case you haven't found it yourself: There is an *excellent* resource about hexagonal grids at http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons (including neighbor search, distance computation and even path finding with obstacles)

Comment: Did `openSet.add` return `false`?

Comment: @Marco13 thank you for useful information!

Comment: @harold I guess so. It returns false every time when set already contained the element

Comment: Well that's bad, that means you would not update the parent/G of a node that you find a better route to. You could try removing the node before adding it.

Comment: @harold omg, that actually works, thank you so much! I can't vote up your comment now but I will when I reach the 15th rep score.

Comment: @harold Good catch. You might consider extending this to an answer, including a few words about *why* it did not work, and the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TreeSet` is not suitable for this usage. It is defined in terms of the comparator (ignoring the implementation of `equals`), but it is both possible and common to have multiple nodes (that really need to be there) with the same F score in the Open set. This will cause both the loss of nodes that should have been there, and the pointless presence of duplicates.

Removing a node before inserting it is not a real solution by the way, just a quick hack that (apparently) makes it work some of the time. You should not regard that suggestion as an acceptable solution, fundamental changes should be applied.

A commonly mentioned approach is maintaining a linked priority queue and hash map, where the priority queue updates the hash map to keep track of where a node with given coordinates occurs in the queue. This enables querying the Open set for "contains" quickly (hashmap), removing a node-with-given-coordinates from the queue quickly (hashmap, then tell the queue to remove the node at the given index), and still gives quick access to the node with lowest F score (as usual).

This arrangement can not be made with built-in ordered containers, since the queue needs to know about the hash map and update it. Fortunately a binary heap is not that hard to implement, and it has already been done too so you may be able to borrow an existing implementation.

Comment: I thought about using simple priority queue since I don't need "contains" and "remove node with given coords" for open set. Is that right?

Comment: @GrastaSsS then there will be "dead nodes" in the Open set, nodes that correspond to a suboptimal prefix and can therefore never contribute to an optimal route, and time will be wasted on evaluating these paths. It should still find the optimal path however.

Comment: Okay, I got it.